# How to correctly mix html and Session data to form an html element

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mixing

I have the following anchor element:

```
 <a href="/cabinet/inbox/1">
```

That 1 in the url is supposed to be dynamic and be taken from Session data. So I need to mix it somewhat like this:

```
<a href="/cabinet/inbox/"@(String)Session["officerID"]
```

But I don't know how exactly this should be done. And besides, I also need to check if for some reason the Session["officerID"] is null like this:

```
 <a href="/cabinet/inbox/"@Session["officerID"]!=null?"0":(string)Session["officerID"]
```

But it seems as I need to put `@` multiple times because in certain cases intellisense does not suggest the C# code.

In fact, I wanted to retrieve that value from ViewModel by strongly typing the view to System.String. But the current view is the master page for another view, which is strongly typed to a custom class. And it seems to be impossible for master page to have different view model than that of the slave one. So I decided to go the Session way.

**UPDATE**

To overcome the problem of having to write `@` multiple times I just need to to wrap the whole expression in brackets like this:

```
<a href="/cabinet/inbox/"@((String)Session["officerID"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Session` in a view. Use `ViewBag`, like so:

```
<a href="/cabinet/inbox/@(ViewBag.OfficerID ?? 0)"></a>
```

where are some point in your controller you've something like this line of code:

```
ViewBag.OfficerID = 42;
```

ViewBag is a dynamic object that will be evaluated at runtime. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx for specifics.